# Why are common Erlang application (Common Test, Dialyzer, leex, yecc etc.) not available in the `erl` shell?

Tags: erlang, erl

Getting back to Erlang and I noticed that I am unable to run any of the supporting frameworks that have their own user guides, such as EUnit, Common Test, leex, yecc, Dyalizer, Typer etc.

According to the [Common Test User's Guide](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/common_test/install_chapter.html), "*the Common Test application is installed with the Erlang/OTP system*" and that "*no extra installation step is required*". I assume that this is true to the others as well and I'm sure that I'm missing something basic.

Comment: All these tools have some suitable  Erlang "entry point" function and calling this function should work (assuming you are not starting your node/shell in embedded mode). Is this perhaps a misconception caused by the shell's autocomplete function which is based on what is already loaded?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried putting in the functions explicitly, but I guess I'm not a good typer... I also updated my answer, but technically it is your answer, so if you submit your own then I will accept it; wouldn't like to take credit for it.

Answer (score 1):

@aronisstav hit the nail on the head with his comment about "*a misconception caused by the shell's autocomplete function which is based on what is already loaded*". To quote him again, the correct answer is:

> All these tools have some suitable Erlang "entry point" function and
>   calling this function should work (assuming you are not starting your
>   node/shell in embedded mode).

Gave these below a try and they worked (I guess I was just an idiot):

```
6> leex:file("./program.erl").
./program.erl.xrl: no such file or directory
error
7> dialyzer:gui().
```

To have the shell autocomplete working, simply load the modules by using  [`code:load_file/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#load_file-1) or `l(Module)` in the `erl` shell:

```
$ erl

1> code:load_file(ct).
{module,ct}

2> l(dialyzer).
{module,dialyzer}
```

Comment: The fact that the modules are not "pre-loaded" does not make them "unavailable". You don't really need to load them explicitly; as long as they are in the load path, calling any function in there will automatically load them (assuming you are not starting your node/shell in embedded mode). All these tools have some suitable  Erlang "entry point", which can be used without an explicit `l(...)`.